# git submodule status shows wrong tag/branch

Tags: git, git-submodules

When I run the command `git submodule status`, I see references to tags from months or even years ago. Everything else works fine (the code checks out what I expect it to, and there is no other weird behaviour).

The issue is that this one command displaying it incorrectly. Everything works fine. `git submodule update` always gets what I expect, and I frequently update the submodules with `git add` and `git push`.

```
username:~/src/main (master)$ git submodule status
 3f786850e387550fdab836ed7e6dc881de23001b module0 (old-tag-1234-g8f123456)
 89e6c98d92887913cadf06b2adb97f26cde4849b module1 (years-old-tag-4321-g12f4567890)
 2b66fd261ee5c6cfc8de7fa466bab600bcfe4f69 module2 (heads/master)
 e983f374794de9c64e3d1c1de1d490c0756eeeff module3 (heads/master)
```

This is strange, because ALL of my submodules have the `master` branch checked out. I would expect this command to show me `heads/master` for all 4 of the modules.

```
username:~/src/main/module0 (master)$ git status 
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

...

username:~/src/main/module3 (master)$ git status 
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

These submodules are properly referenced too - a `git submodule update` does not result in any changes to them. This is a repository updated dozens of times daily by dozens of people - There is zero chance that we're accidentally using code from 3 years ago, or forgot to update it.

To further emphasise: **The issue is that this one command displaying it incorrectly. Everything works fine**

Can anyone suggest reason's why? I suspect this might be something to do with needing to do a `update-ref` for everything, or some kind of stale refs in `~/src/main/.git/modules/module0/info/refs`

Comment: It's not *wrong*, it's just not what *you want*. (Well, we can easily define that as "wrong", and then it *is* wrong.  But...) What `git submodule status` is doing is running `git describe` in each submodule. That's `git describe`, not `git describe --all`. So each submodule Git is not looking at any of the branch names, and won't "describe" the submodule as `master`, because that's a *branch* name and `git describe` uses *annotated tags*.

Comment: There's no way to make `git submodule status` use `git describe --all`. You can however use `git submodule foreach` to run `git describe --all` in each submodule. (Based on the `heads/master` for two of them, `git submodule status` must be using `--always`, which falls back on branch names when there are no tags. Would be nice if one could control this easier...)

Comment: Recommend converting this comment to an answer. Its a good question & answer.  IMO git submodule status should behave like this answer to comply with the principal of least surprise.  I have had this question and others have come to me asking the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same head scratcher after updating my clone of the [Pico C/C++ SDK](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk) to the latest commits on the master branch. Here is my solution based on the suggestions from the comments.

Standard answer from `git submodule status` implied that the submodule `btstack` got **downgraded** by the update

```bash
$ git submodule status
 72ef1732c954d938091467961e41f4aa9b976b34 lib/btstack (v1.4-2371-g72ef1732c)
 8ef38a6d32c54f850bff8f189bdca19ded33792a lib/cyw43-driver (v1.0.1)
 239918ccc173cb2c2a62f41a40fd893f57faf1d6 lib/lwip (STABLE-2_1_0_RELEASE-548-g239918cc)
 a77287f8fa6b76f74984121fdafc8563147435c8 lib/mbedtls (v2.28.1-36-ga77287f8f)
 86c416d4c0fb38432460b3e11b08b9de76941bf5 lib/tinyusb (0.15.0)
```

Solution using `git submodule foreach` revealed the actual truth

(**NOTE** assumes that the reader is using a *NIX shell like bash)

```bash
$ git submodule foreach --quiet 'echo "" $(git rev-list -n1 HEAD) $sm_path $(git describe --all | sed "s,^tags/,(,;s/$/)/")'
 72ef1732c954d938091467961e41f4aa9b976b34 lib/btstack (v1.5.6.1-1-g72ef1732c)
 8ef38a6d32c54f850bff8f189bdca19ded33792a lib/cyw43-driver (v1.0.1)
 239918ccc173cb2c2a62f41a40fd893f57faf1d6 lib/lwip (STABLE-2_1_0_RELEASE-548-g239918cc)
 a77287f8fa6b76f74984121fdafc8563147435c8 lib/mbedtls (v2.28.1-36-ga77287f8f)
 86c416d4c0fb38432460b3e11b08b9de76941bf5 lib/tinyusb (0.15.0)
```

The addition of sed is of course only sugar coating to match the outputs of the commands.

**EDIT**

To save the reader from quoting hell. the same thing as git alias (**S**ub**M**odule**S**tatus) for inclusion in `~/.gitconfig`:

```ini
[alias]
...
   sms = submodule foreach --quiet 'echo \"\" $(git rev-list -n1 HEAD) $sm_path $(git describe --all | sed -e s,^tags/,\\(, -e s/$/\\)/)'
...
```

```bash
$ git sms
 72ef1732c954d938091467961e41f4aa9b976b34 lib/btstack (v1.5.6.1-1-g72ef1732c)
 8ef38a6d32c54f850bff8f189bdca19ded33792a lib/cyw43-driver (v1.0.1)
 239918ccc173cb2c2a62f41a40fd893f57faf1d6 lib/lwip (STABLE-2_1_0_RELEASE-548-g239918cc)
 a77287f8fa6b76f74984121fdafc8563147435c8 lib/mbedtls (v2.28.1-36-ga77287f8f)
 86c416d4c0fb38432460b3e11b08b9de76941bf5 lib/tinyusb (0.15.0)
```